# How to Get Domain Url From Page

Tags: php, html, preg-match

i am trying to get exact domain url from html page

i trying this url only return from v.html

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/114948445121686813006/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCMLjxpef1rHJ3QE#5929911272604125650
```

but my php function show all urls

v.html have html code and links

this is my php code

```
<?php


$string=file_get_contents("v.html");

function getUrls($string)
{
    $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    return ($matches[0]);
}

 $urls = getUrls($string);

 foreach($urls as $url)
 {
    echo $url.'<br />';
 }


?>
```

Output

```
http://www.w3.org/2007/app
http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007
http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
http://purl.org/atom/app#
http://www.w3.org/2007/app
http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007
http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
http://purl.org/atom/app#
http://www.w3.org/2007/app
http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
http://purl.org/atom/app#
http://www.w3.org/2007/app
https://picasaweb.google.com/114948445121686813006/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCMLjxpef1rHJ3QE#5929911272604125650
```

Comment: pica have an api, why are you scraping?

Comment: i did not get document for get photo url after upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PHP function `strpos()` at its output.
With him search for "https" and find your URL

```
$findme   = 'https://';
$pos = strpos($output, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
if ($pos === false) {
    // not found in the output
} else {
    // found in the output
}
```

or try this:

```
foreach($urls as $url) { 
   if (strstr($url,'picasaweb.google.com')) { 
      echo $url; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: i already done this i just want this url return
https://picasaweb.google.com/114948445121686813006/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCMLjxpef1rHJ3QE#5929911272604125650

Comment: This URL will always be constant or it will vary at times @user2489961?

Comment: authkey=abcd will chnage other will same

Comment: You can always get a part of the variable that does not change with the strpos(), like a "picasaweb.google.com", and from there calculate the start and end of string

Comment: Try this:
`foreach($urls as $url)
 {
    if (strstr($url,'picasaweb.google.com')) {
        echo $url;
    }
 }`

Comment: I edited the answer above, check
+1

Answer (score -1):

Using JavaScript you can get that using

this.document.location.href

Comment: He asked to use PHP not JS.

Comment: @user0000001 His first line says "i am trying to get exact domain url from html page". that does not imply php, and very rarely do you develop php in isolation of js and css